# Why do we need to "enter" 32-bit protected mode anyway?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

Recently I've been interested in building an tiny-toy-OS from scratch, and I am really confused now. May you help me please..

### The questions

I am getting stuck with understanding that why do we even bother to enter a 32-bit protected mode?

I mean why not just overwrite the old instructions from 16-bit into 32-bit (or 64-bit) so we can coding straightforward (e.g. accessing more memory addresses directly)... what's the point of this switching-process...why why why...

The reason why I am confused is that the tutorial I am reading first teaches me how to boot with 16-bit (some basic BIOS instructions) while it claims that "32-bit is better" which I totally agree and so we have to enter 32-bit protected mode. In my opinion this is just a simple extension of length of bits? why so different (tough to use BIOS, GDT, e-registers...)?

Comment: There are many differences between the 16-bit mode and the 32-bit mode. And, at the time when 32-bit was introduced, booting into 16-bit mode and then switching to 32-bit mode was required for backward compatibility.

Comment: IMO, there's lots of neat stuff to learn / do with asm in user-space under existing OSes.  Once you're comfortable with that, learning the OS-dev side of things is much easier: you can read and understand *what* any example is doing, you just need to read why without also puzzling through the mechanics of the instructions.

Comment: In this case, the answer is obvious if you know how the machine encoding of x86 instructions works: there's a default operand size depending on mode, and the operand-size prefix `0x66` flips sets it to the non-default size (16 in 32 or 64-bit mode), potentially causing a length-changing-prefix stall in the pre-decode stage on Intel CPUs (http://agner.org/optimize/), if the instruction without the prefix would have had an imm32, but with the prefix has only an imm16 and thus is shorter.  (Or for 16-bit addressing modes, disp32 vs. disp16.)

Comment: Anyway, obviously for code-size reasons you don't want almost every instruction to need a `0x66` prefix, like it would if the only available default operand size was 16 bits.  Especially back when 386 was designed, code-size was even more important than it is these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel has always tried to keep their CPUs backward compatible (and still is).
A new fancy CPU that can't run any existing software is as good as a rock for the industry.

The opcode `b8` is `mov ax, imm16`, there are no other possible ways to interpret it, including `mov eax, imm32`, without breaking compatibility.
Unless you set a flag, somewhere, that let the CPU know it is OK to do so.
That's *switching*, and now `b8` is `mov eax, imm32`.
So, the old instructions have been "overwritten" in a sense.

Intel could have used totally new opcodes but that'd be a huge waste of opcodes (and the opcode space was already *very* crowded at the time), plus going down this road and avoiding an explicit switch, the CPU would have to be both in real mode and in protected mode (since it cannot drop support for 16-bit code).
That's a call for very messy design or in the best a nightmare.

[Peter Cordes pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743371/why-do-we-need-to-enter-32-bit-protected-mode-anyway/48746005?noredirect=1#comment84504113_48746005) that a prefix could be used if it weren't for the troubles with handling interrupts (and possibly any mechanism where the CPU performs automatic actions).

Protected mode come along with a new protection scheme, it's admittedly over-engineered but nevertheless, we need to deal with it, its GDT, IDT, TSS and so on.
This mechanism was set *before* the advent of 32-bit computing on the x86 architecture, i.e. it was present in the 286 when no 32-bit registers/addresses were present.
When Intel recognized the need for 32-bit computing it took the opportunity to ship it along with a revamped version of the protection scheme.

Whenever a new contract between the CPU and the software is developed, it always customary to require an *explicit intention* from the software, this prevents any spurious activation.

So switching provides:

- An easier design.
- A reuse of the opcodes (avoiding the need for prefixes).
- A proof that the software is written to understand the new contract.
- The same environment for the software that doesn't understand the new contract.

With the advent of UEFI, some constraints have been relaxed, a UEFI bootloader (or any application or driver) boots in 64-bit mode (or 32-bit if the CPU is too old for 64-bit).
If you feel unhappy with the legacy BIOS boot, you can experiment with UEFI.
Beware that 64-bit mode relies on everything that went before it, including protected mode and PAE paging.
You may get away with shoving them under the rug for some time, but if you plan to keep coding an OS, mastering the basics will pay off.

Comment: The straightforward way would have been to still have 16-bit be the default operand / address size, and rely on prefixes to set 32-bit operand size.  I think every 32-bit operand-size / address-size instruction is encodeable with prefixes in 16-bit mode (except VEX prefixes, which would have been designed differently if x86 actually worked this way).  This is obviously horrible for code-size, because almost every instruction would need a `0x66` operand-size prefix, and many would need address-size as well.

Comment: But since you still absolutely need a new mode for interrupts to push 32-bit EFLAGS/EIP, it would be insane not to do something like the current design and change the default operand size.

Comment: is this correct "UEFI bootloader boots in 64-bit mode" ? i was under the impression that they switch to 64-bit mode in first couple of instructions.